# Get column names of all tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to generate column names (and it's type if possible) of all tables in database.

Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select c.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c;
```

This has name, type, and a lot of other information for all tables in a *database* -- note, not on a server but in a database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to list the columns of a given table.

```
create table tbl1 (id int)
Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name in ('tbl1')
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78050def02ea21dd90aad3f22da0d62a)

You can also use sys.columns as shown below

```
SELECT TAB.name AS TableName
    ,TAB.object_id AS ObjectID
    ,COL.name AS ColumnName
    ,COL.user_type_id AS DataTypeID
FROM sys.columns COL
INNER JOIN sys.tables TAB ON COL.object_id = TAB.object_id
    -- where TAB.name = '<TABLENAME>'
    -- Uncomment above line and add <Table Name> to fetch details for particular table
    -- where COL.name = '<COLUMNNAME>'
    -- Uncomment above line and add <Column Name> to fetch details for particular column names
```

[**Demo of sys.columns**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8bb719a3b424115b347b5989695ce73).

For the complete information of different types of result for a given table i.e., column name, data type and there size you can refer [this reference](https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-cheat-sheet-retrieving-column-description-sql-server/).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: `(<tbl1>, <tbl2>)` what is this for? It says `<` syntax error

Comment: @DignityDignity You need to pass here table name

Comment: I'd just add to the answer that this is the approach for listing columns of a specific table because OP is asking for "all tables in database"

Comment: @B001ᛦ Are you saying or asking something from me.

Comment: I'm recommending this to you